# Saludos a todos, tengo un problema, laravel 8 me da error en los namespace en todos los archivos de php, a pesar de eso la aplicación funciona

Tags: php, laravel, vscode, composer

Debido a las circunstancias me toco reiniciar mi pc de fabrica y tuve que volver a instalar wamp, xampp con php8, composer, node, laravel, visual studio code, etc. Antes de reiniciar mi pc de fabrica no tenia este problema, que ahora cuando creo un proyecto de laravel me da un error en los namespace, la aplicación funciona pero vs code me los detecta como errores los namespace, pero si abro otros proyectos de laravel que tengo no los detecta como errores, necesito ayuda por favor.

[image: Imagen de las rutas de API me marca como error en los namespace y use pero la aplicación funciona]

[image: Captura de los errores que me marca el editor pero la aplicación sigue funcionando]

[image: Otro ejemplo de dichos errores]

Comment: Amigo, el codigo deberia colocarlo en textos..!

Comment: Intenta ejecutar en la consola composer dump-autoload